# How to Divide a weighted cyclic graph into n graphs, breaking as few connections as possible

Tags: java, optimization, graph-algorithm

**Background for the question:**

At the start of every new year at my daughters school the principal always talks about how difficult it is to divide the kids into classes because they have many requests as to who they want to be in class with, and the kindergarden also has some recommendations.

In my mind that is just a weighted, cyclic graph with kids as nodes and requests/recommendations as edges that needs to be split.

**The question:**

Imagine if you will, a graph with cycles and weighted edges, possibly disconnected. 
I would like to divide that graph into n smaller graphs with at least s nodes in each and at most t nodes in each graph while breaking as few edges as possible.
I assume it is NP hard to solve, so it might be an optimization problem really.

1. Does this graph algorithm have name?
2. Are there any java libraries that can help me solve this?

Thanks,
Jesper

Comment: This is not NP hard problem and constructing a graph can be done in Polynomial time.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim whilst I wouldn't claim to be in any way knowledgeable about graph algorithms, I can't help but feel your comment is a bit [Fermat-esque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem).

Comment: @Jesper there may be a good algorithm; but noting that "you can't please all the people all the time", and that there isn't really a need for a fast algorithm (as in, this has to be run just once a year, right?), my first attempt would be a random search: just generate a whole bunch of possible partitionings, and see which is best. If that doesn't generate a good solution, try a better strategy like genetic algorithms.

Comment: @AndyTurner, Rigth, speed of the algorithm in big-O terms is not that important as it would be run infrequent and on a small dataset ~ 7*30 pupils starting each year at this point.

Comment: @AndyTurner, What technique would you use to generate the partitions ensuring that the solutions will be reasonable good.

Comment: @Jesper I wouldn't worry about "reasonably good" in the first instance; see if the randomness will find something good.

Comment: @Jesper I'm interested in the directedness here: in what circumstances would a graph containing "Andy in the same class as Jesper" not also contain "Jesper in the same class as Andy"? Is this on the basis of individual requests? (e.g. child A asks to be in the same class as child B, but not the other way round? Awkward...)

Comment: @AndyTurner, Each student has the possibility to add 0-3 wished classmates (anonymously). So A might request B and C, while B only requests C.
So the edges will have directions.
In version 2, I envision request priorities and negative edge values if a kid or kindergarden requests two kids to be seperated

Comment: I guess, you should provide some test data (a CSV with line like `name1; name2; weight` should do). Ideally, a whole graph of the 7*30 pupils you're speaking about (anonymize the data if needed). Then the chances are higher that someone cares to implement some solution (I guess, I could try; just drop me a note).

Answer (score 0):

A component of a graph is also a graph. Last year i had to write code for image stitching which made use of directed graph datastructure which had 64000 pixels and it was not slow at all.[image: image second]  [image: image first] [image]

The resulting image is the last one and code is here [github](https://github.com/afrazsalim/Gegevens-en-algorithm/tree/master/Image%20stitching).

Well, in your case you can create a graph datastructur. Create a one dimensional array of Linkedlist and within that linklist save the datastructure connected with three arguments, first one is your first one student, second one is student to which the first one is connected and third one is number which expresses strength bound between them.: Example student 1 is connected to student 5 with strength == 100 then it you create a new node `Connected c = new connected(1,5,100);` and add it to first entry of array like this: `array[i].add(c) where i == 1`.

**Search:Which student is connected to which one:** When you try to find which student is connect to which one then you simple go that array index like:

```
`for(Connected c : array[i].get();
        int firstStudent = c.getFirst()
        int secondStudent = c.getSecond()
         int strength = c.getStrength();`
```

Your linked list should have an iterator so that you can travers.

This is what it actually looks like:
  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I like your datastructure approach, but the question is more about what algorithm to use to determine the classes. The challenge is to break as few connections as possible and still fit them into classes of correct size.
So far Andy suggested doing it more or less random until a good solution was found.

Comment: @Jesper i think you did not get my point, your all linkedlists are sub-classes. let me clear it, remove only one student from linkedlist and put it's all succesors in priority queue , there by i mean that all students to which this student is connected and you can do this in linear time because you have N linkedlists for N students.

Comment: Now start removing students out of priority queue one by one who is most likedly to bounded to this student and put all succesor of removed student in prioty and keep doing this you will get a sequence of increasing students in decreasing number if two students are not connected they will fall seperate no need to do anything.

Comment: Missed your point, sorry. So 1) Create a graph of sorts 2) Create the array of linked lists with Connected. 3) Create school-classes by using a priority queue to pick most connected student 4) repeat with the picked student from 3. 

What I do not understand is in 2 when do I begin a new linked list in the ArrayList? And in 3 when do I start a new school-class?

Answer (score 0):

This problem sounds like a minimum cut problem but for directed graph.

> In graph theory, a minimum cut of a graph is a cut (a partition of the
>   vertices of a graph into two disjoint subsets that are joined by at
>   least one edge) that is minimal in some sense. [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut)

One not optimized solution for the problem you described is to find all connected components and find the minimum cut for each (which result in breaking them) until all resulting components satisfy your criteria.

Now the issue with this method is that algorithms I know for minimum cut work for undirected graphs. In my search on the topic I found an [article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2ee8/c773ef22776b0113c78325ca76b701cbb78e.pdf) for this problem which might be of use.

Comment: Yes, that was also my initial idea. And I figured that there must be a bunch of great java libraries for these kind of problems. I just cannot seem to find them.
I am currently working on a estimation where I create the graph and then start at one student and then adding one at a time based the highest scoring connections. Like @Luai is suggesting.
I will keep your input on minimum cut handy. Thanks!